# Function that will generate 1, 2, 4, 3?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is there a function that will generate 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3... ?

I arrived at the values through the sequence 2^n mod 5, and I need to write it in terms of n mod 4.

So far I have found that it can be expressed as 1 + (((n mod 4)((n mod 4) + 1) / 2) mod 4), or 1 + sum(0 : n mod 4) mod 4. Is there a simpler to write it?

Comment: make a table, case operator, let k=n mod 4, if k=0 then 1 else if k=1 then 2 else if k=2 then 4 else 3

Comment: $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }x\equiv 0 \pmod 4 \\2 & \text{if }x\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\4 & \text{if }x\equiv 2 \pmod 4 \\3 & \text{if }x\equiv 3 \pmod 4 \end{cases} $$ is a perfectly good function already. Or why not $$f(x) = 2^{n\bmod 4}\bmod 5 \;?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you are looking for, but would $\dfrac{10}{4}-\dfrac{3}{2}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}n\right)-\dfrac{1}{2}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}n\right)$ work?

Comment: It almost works, but it was a requirement to use n mod 4. Still, its a good answer, how did you derive that formula?

Comment: In that case, you can also use $\dfrac{10}{4}-\dfrac{3}{2}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}(n\mod 4)\right)-\dfrac{1}{2}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}(n\mod 4)\right)$. You can derive that formula by taking the inverse discrete Fourier transform of the sequence.